# Why is this SQL statement being read incorrectly?

Tags: mysql, wordpress

Why is this SQL Statement

```
$array = $wpdb->get_results('SELECT * FROM wp_before_after WHERE patient = '.$patientName );
```

Generating this error?

WordPress database error: [Unknown column 'sarah' in 'where clause']
SELECT * FROM wp_before_after WHERE patient = sarah-jordon

It's like it's swapping round 'patient' and 'sarah-jordon', and thinking sarah-jordon is a column in the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing quotes around your value.

```
$array = $wpdb->get_results('SELECT * FROM wp_before_after WHERE patient = "'.$patientName . '"');
```

But it will be more robust if you use a parameterized query.

#### Edit

I checked quickly in wordpress reference, and they have a **prepare** method

Comment: You mean a prepared statement?

Comment: Exactly. I don't know how it works with wordpress but I guess they have something to do that

Comment: And, it's much safer... what would happen if someone enters: ' sarah; DROP TABLE wp_before_after` into your "Patient Name" field? [This looks like it might be a helpful reference](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb)

Answer (score 0):

While A.D.'s answer is correct...

```
$array = $wpdb->get_results('SELECT * FROM wp_before_after WHERE patient = "'.$patientName . '"');
```

... and makes mention that the OP example is not really robust/secure (vulnerable to SQL injections) I thought it would be worthwhile to post an example that *is secure* using the `prepare` statement:

```
// Usage: $wpdb->prepare( 'query' [, value_parameter, value_parameter ... ] );

// Example:
$patient_name = .$patientName;
$patient = $wpdb->get_var( 
   $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT * FROM wp_before_after WHERE patient = %d",    $patient_name ));
```

[Documentation can be found here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb)

The reason for using `prepare` is it prevents SQL Injection Attacks *on queries that take parameters*. For example, in the OP example, if someone were to enter..

`sarah; DROP TABLE wp_before_after`

or maybe less insidiously:

`sarah OR 1=1`

.. into the `Patient Name` field, that SQL would be executed and presumably drop your `wp_before_after` table or return *all* of the records in your `patient` table.

The `prepare` method SQL escapes the values prior to executing the query -- and that prevents your variables/parameters from being potentially read as SQL. It's basically saying "hey, make sure you read these as values, not part of the query."

As a general rule of thumb, you want to use `prepare` *in all circumstances where a query takes user input as a parameter*. You do not want to use `prepare` in circumstances where no user input is needed -- for example, getting all patients with a first name starting with 's'.

Comment: Is this necessary even if there is no field, and it's simply just a read from a database row? There's no input form or anyway for any user to access this query other than PHP, ie. Me

Comment: As a rule of thumb - I would say - any time you need to use a variable within your query string, you should let the db engine know to treat it as a value, not SQL. How is the value stored in `.$patientName` getting there?

Comment: It's best practice to prevent SQL injection attacks, but "necessary"..? No, not if you don't care if `.$patientName` is unsanitized / unescaped.